# App rejected due to temporary entitlement I need for NSSavePanel

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-approval, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

this is the second time my Mac app has been rejected by the MAS. 
I use a temporary entitlement so that the user can store his backup file the app created on his device. 
This is the response I am getting from the MAS to my rejection:

```
We've determined that one or more temporary entitlement exceptions requested for 
this app are not appropriate and will not be granted:

com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write  /
```

Very vague and the second time they are not telling me what is wrong with what i'm doing.

For that I use following entitlement:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<string>True</string>
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
<array>
    <string>/</string>
</array>
```

And this is how I use the entitlement:

```
NSSavePanel* saveSelection = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

[saveSelection setPrompt:@"Export"];
[saveSelection setMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Save your encrypted backup file to:",@"")];
[saveSelection setNameFieldStringValue:date];

[saveSelection beginSheetModalForWindow:kDelegate.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
if (result==NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {....
    }
}
```

I really do hope somebody can help and thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you use the entitlement? That is, why doesn't it work to use the sandbox-compatible save dialog?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how I use the entitlement.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working by adding this to the NSSavePanel:

```
[saveSelection setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"whatever"]];
[saveSelection setAllowsOtherFileTypes:NO];
```

I don't know why this made it work, but it does... at least in my app.